# Only authorize people with a common ID to see something (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like this in the DB:

```
UserID: 1
ClubID: 1

UserID: 2
ClubID: 1

UserID: 3
ClubID: 2
```

I need that User 1 and 2 can see mypage/club/1 because they are in the same club, but not user 3.

This is what I got so far:

This is my middleware

```
class IDmiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->ClubID != $request->id){
            return redirect ('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then I have added it to the routemiddleware in kernel:

```
'id' => IDmiddleware::class
```

And then I do the routing:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'id'], function ($id) {

    Route::get('/clubID/{id}');
});
```

But it doesn't work. Everyone authenticated can see it. Any solution?

Comment: Show your relationship for the user and club model in your question?

Comment: What is the output of `dd(Auth::user(), Auth::user()->ClubID, $request->id);` in the handle method?